# ANGULAR 6 ERROR Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '**'

Tags: angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a newbie at angular 6 and asp.net core web api , i am trying to fetch data from the valuesController getPatients, and will display the result in grid but i am getting this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '**'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '**'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1384)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:100)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:108)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
:44320/api/Values:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
core.js:1673 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

my module-routing.ts is as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { PatientlistComponent } from './patientlist/patientlist.component';
import { AddpatientComponent } from './addpatient/addpatient.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', component: PatientlistComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'patientlist', component: PatientlistComponent },
  { path: 'addpatient', component: AddpatientComponent }
 ]; 



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],  
  declarations: []
})
a

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and appModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

//import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PatientlistComponent } from './patientlist/patientlist.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { AddpatientComponent } from './addpatient/addpatient.component';
import { PatientServiceService } from './patient-service.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   // AppComponent,
    PatientlistComponent,
   AddpatientComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [PatientServiceService],
  //bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  bootstrap: [PatientlistComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please help out in this problem TIA

Answer (score 0):

you have not set proper default route path

you need to set
`{  path: 'your default path ',
    redirectTo: 'redirect url',
    pathMatch: 'full', 
}`

Comment: hi bhagwat as i am newbie to angular can you please tell what would be the default path ? the redirect Url would be my web api controller like localhost:45318/api/controllername ?

Comment: if you want to use angular routing then you need to set `<base href="/">` in `index.html` file. Then add `{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/patientlist', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: hi bhagwat i use the same but unfortunately its not working either, and i am unable to get my data from web api

Comment: HI sa fa please go through these link [https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing application default(/) route. Please add a default route hope it will work.

Comment: default route? where>